# fixed menu:hover in absolute centered form container below

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the container and fix the menu at top. But the Hover in .nav  doesn't work. When I cut the absolute property it works, and when I keep the absolute property and cut the `top right bottom left 0` it works too. Why does it happen?

```
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{

            background-color: black;
        }
        .menu{
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            height: 10%;
            width: 100%;
            color: white;
            background-color: orange;
            border-radius: 10px;
            left: 0;
        }
        .nav{
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: black;
            height: 90%;
            width: 26%;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-right:3%;
            margin-left: 3%;
            margin-top: 4px;

        }
        .nav:hover{
            background-color: blue;
            color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .container{
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            color: white;
        }
        form{
            position: relative;
            background-color: grey;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 10%;
        }
        form:hover{
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px white;
            transition: all 1s;
        }
        input{
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        input:hover{
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px white;
            transition: all 1s;
        }
    </style>

</head>
        <body>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="nav">
                    Consulta    
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    Venta
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    Agregar
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container" id="consulta">
                <form>
                      First name:<br>
                      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
                      <br>
                      Last name:<br>
                      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
                      <br><br>
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Kudal, welcome to stack overflow. Someone was kind enough to edit your post as to be more concise and clear on the question being asked. If an answer has answered your question, please accept it (by clicking on the check mark) so we know that you have obtained the help you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a z-index on the .menu class

```
 .menu{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        background-color: orange;
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjWBRJ)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your `.container` is also absolutely positioned, and stuck to top thanks to `top:0`. As in your Html, your container come after the menu, it is automatically displayed above.

As @Georgette Pincin said, you can add a `z-index` to the menu, in order to keep it above the container, or you also can edit the container `top` value to make it start under the menu ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u3t7ouv/)):

```
.container{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Great! Understood! So mouse didn't recognize the menu because the container was there! You guys are awesome! thanks!